# Use react-md in gatsby js

Tags: reactjs, sass, material-design, gatsby

I'm trying to use React Material Design (`react-md`) within my Gatsby JS project and am finding that the CSS rules are not being applied. So when I import a component like a `Button` and render the component, it has no styling on it whatsoever.

Here is what I did to install `react-md`:

In my `gatsby-config.js` I added the following

```
plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-sass'
]
```

And then, under `layouts>index.scss` I have

```
@import '~react-md/src/scss/react-md';
```

And then I import that into my `layouts>index.js` as

```
import './index.scss'
```

---

When I render a `Button` component, it does not have any styling. I inspected the component and it has all the correct CSS classNames applied to it, but the rules do not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `index.scss` in layouts folder

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Roboto:400,500,700|Material+Icons'); //optional
@import '~react-md/src/scss/react-md'; // Required
$md-primary-color: $md-teal-500; //optional colors
$md-secondary-color: $md-purple-a-400; //optional colors
@include react-md-everything; // Required
```

NOTE: with `@include react-md-everything;` you get whole react-md css library.

If you want to minimize CSS prefer to use `@import` per respective react-md-component based on the following format:

`@include react-md-components`

e.g. use `@include react-md-buttons` to the scss-file of your react component where you want to import and use a `<Button/>` from react-md

Documentation: [Minimizing Bundle - react-md docs](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/customization/minimizing-bundle)

Comment: Works! Thank you very much